# Is there any way of good quality to follow up the update papers from many subcategories in arXiv.org?

Tags: publications, arxiv, tools

Could any one recommend any approach to keep up with the recent papers in arXiv.org? Papers from many subcategories are considered. 
PS: of course, a better way than just read the sites of each subcategory.

Comment: Just use the website.

Comment: RSS is a better way!@NajibIdrissi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

arXiv has an RSS feed organised by subject, e.g., http://export.arxiv.org/rss/math, so you can use a standard RSS feed app.

Comment: Thank you for your rss link. Now I use [Feedly](http://feedly.com) to see the updates in the arXiv.org.